# ElasticSearch query specifying an indexname using todays date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, timelion

I'm using logstash to populate ES with a number of metrics from our live services across a number of machines. Logstash creates a new index each day and i am finding that querying ES without specifying the index, is running slowly. ( i currently maintain 5 days of indicies). If i specify the specific index eg today

```
.es(index=logstash-2018.01.15, q= examplequery
```

it runs very quickly
Is there a way i can specify todays index using the date field?

eg

```
.es(index=logstash-'get date', q= examplequery
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query for getting the indices of today's date:

```
 .es(index='<logstash-{now/d}>')
```

An interesting read with all the options available in elastic search to include date math in index names:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the syntax I guess you are using Timelion or something that uses query string. There is a good tutorial here that includes specifying index patterns:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-tutorial-from-zero-to-hero
In your case it will be

```
.es(index=logstash-*, q= examplequery
```

or

```
.es(index=logstash-2018.01.*, q= examplequery
```

if you need this year january and the index pattern is 'logstash-YYYY.MM.dd'

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using timelion to create dashboards and i would like to specify only todays index. I have tested that this speeds things up by using a similar syntax to what you have suggested but also specifying the day.  ''.es(index=logstash-2018.01.15 *, q= examplequery'' I would like a way to specify todays date and for it to work for each day of the year. The above example will search each index of January which is still slow to respond.

Comment: do you mean you want to specify the index as a variable?

Comment: I found these:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timelion-how-generate-label-dynamically/85072 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timelion-assign-a-time-series-to-a-variable-and-then-refer-to-it-using-that-variable/111086
 This suggests for me that you can't get the current date to a variable.